# Writing an OpenCL kernel in C++?

Tags: c++, c, graphics, gpu, opencl

Recently, I've been following a tutorial named [Ray Tracing in One Weekend](https://raytracing.github.io/books/RayTracingInOneWeekend.html). So far, I've done some optimizations to the code written from reading the tutorial. I've even added multicore support, allowing me to take advantage of all CPUs to render the images faster. However, I still would get very low FPS.

Therefore, I've started to get OpenCL up and running on my project, however I need to access C++ objects from the OpenCL kernel, even though OpenCL only supports C99.

Does anybody know how I can accept C++ objects and decode them so that I can access them in my OpenCL kernel, or if there's a way to create OpenCL kernels using C++?

Comment: Why do you spam the C tag watchers with your C++ question?

Comment: @273K Sorry, because it was related to OpenCL's C99 language. As someone moving from C to C++ I thought it'd also be relevant to C programming, as both languages are pretty relevant in this case.

Comment: [tag:c++]: *Do not also tag questions with [c] unless you have a good reason.* [tag:c]: *C is distinct from C++ and it should not be combined with the C++ tag without a specific reason.*

Comment: _however I need to access C++ objects from the OpenCL kernel, even though OpenCL only supports C99_ Why? If OpenCL is C only, any pointers to objects will be those defined by OpenCL (which are in C). If you have C++ objects, they are ones that _you've_ defined, so you can't pass them to OpenCL because it doesn't know about them. Please _edit_ your question and post some sample code that shows what you're trying to do.

Comment: @273K IMO, OP _has_ a reason to tag both, since the question is about interfacing C++ code to a C based library. The linked code is C++ and OP wants to adapt this to use OpenCL (which is C only).

Comment: https://www.khronos.org/sycl/

Comment: SYCL answers the question of how to write compute shaders in C++. However, it's naive to think you can use this to simply import any host C++ objects to manipulate them in your GPU code. OOP C++ data structures are at best array-of-structs/classes (AOS), while vector processing is typically most efficient with struct-of-arrays (SOA) designs. And that doesn't even begin to get into how thread synchronisation is fundamentally VERY different in GPU code than the mutexes typically used in CPU code.